# How to reload the content of iframe on menu item's click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the content of iframe by clicking on menu items. But the content of iframe does not refresh for some reason.

**HTML**

```
<div class="switcher">
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/rLIgC">Option 1</a>
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/ejBJw">Option 2</a>
</div>

<iframe class="switch-target" width="300" height="300" src=""></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
var switcher$ = $('.switcher');
var switchTarget$ = $('.switch-target');

switcher$.on('click', switchIframeSrc);

function switchIframeSrc() {
  switchTarget$.attr('src', switcher$.val());
}

// call the method on load
switchIframeSrc();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but you don't need any JavaScript to do that. Just give your `<iframe>` element a `name` attribute and use that name as a `target` for your hyperlinks.

```html
<div class="switcher">
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/rLIgC" target="switch-frame">Option 1</a>
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/ejBJw" target="switch-frame">Option 2</a>
</div>

<iframe class="switch-target" width="300" height="300" src="" name="switch-frame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you've to prevent the default action that is triggered by the click on an anchor. For this, use the event object and call the following method:

`event.preventDefault();`

And then, pass the element to `switchIframeSrc` which triggered the event:

`switchIframeSrc(event.target);`

---

```js
var switcher$ = $('.switcher');
var switchTarget$ = $('.switch-target');

switcher$.on('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  switchIframeSrc(event.target);
});

function switchIframeSrc(anchor) {
  switchTarget$.attr('src', $(anchor).attr('href'));
}

// call the method on load
switchIframeSrc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switcher">
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/rLIgC">Option 1</a>
  <a href ="https://codepen.io/shawkdsn/pen/ejBJw">Option 2</a>
</div>

<iframe class="switch-target" width="300" height="300" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the horizontal menu, not the combobox.

Comment: @ScalaBoy I've updated the answer. Also, which link do you expect to be opened when the method is called `onload`?